# how do I give style to a TimeTextBox dojo component?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've created this dojo component programatically, like this:

```
    dojo.require("dijit.form.TimeTextBox");
    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    new dijit.form.TimeTextBox({
        name: "prog_val",
        value: new Date(),
        constraints: {
            timePattern: 'HH:mm:ss',
            clickableIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
            visibleIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
            visibleRange: 'T01:00:00'
        }
    },
    "prog_val");
});
```

and this works well , but I am interested in changing the background color of the div that displays the options for the timeTextBox.  I am using dojo 1.6

here it is a JSfiddle of what I'm trying to do :
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsgau)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of the element should be prog_val, hence:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
#prog_val {
background-color:"Cyan"
} 
</style>
```

Adding:

If that isn't the exact element you want to change, then you can find what Dojo has set as the id of any div by inspecting it with Firebug.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I regret ever learning Dojo. The web site is so encouraging and optimistic, but the documentation is so spotty and information is often hidden. Anyway, it looks like you need to override the theme elements you are working with in your css. Here's the article on overriding color in themes in 1.6: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dijit/themes.html#color

Comment: Another thought, I looked inside Common.css for Claro (the Fiddle is using Claro). There might be a background image in that widget; hence, you are not seeing the color at all. There are quite a few in that css, e.g.:.claro .dijitTextBoxFocused {  background-color: #ffffff;   background-image: url('images/textBox_back.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x; }

Answer (score 0):

All of the dijit widgets have a `style` property for this purpose. [Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsgau/2/).
However I didn't understand if you want to change the background color like this, or just the options(every time suggestion) backgrounds. If so consider checking them in firebug and applying styles to the appropriate class(es).

Comment: thanks, that is not what I was looking for, my goal is to set the backgorund of the popup options section.

Comment: So try to find the css class which sets the background and override it. It may be tricky, because the same class may be used by other widget types.

Answer (score 0):

Hand over a `baseClass` property will create a `domNode` with that CSS class.

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.TimeTextBox");
    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    new dijit.form.TimeTextBox({
        name: "prog_val",
        baseClass: "myTimeTextBox",
        value: new Date(),
        constraints: {
            timePattern: 'HH:mm:ss',
            clickableIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
            visibleIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
            visibleRange: 'T01:00:00'
        }
    },
    "prog_val");
});
```